# backbone.dualStorage load from localStorage after refresh

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

I am trying to build an offline capable app with Backbone and dualStorage. I am having a problem where if I go offline and refresh the app 404's.

This is my current start up code. It checks if a cookie is present and if so tries to instantiate that session again. The problem is with the refresh `fetch()` errors out and I get a 404. How do I make dualStorage check the localStorage if online endpoint isn't available?

The localStorage is populated with the right data, and is made so by calling `Session.save();` after successful login.

```
// Start App
Router = new AppRouter({});

var cookieSessionName = window.location.hostname.replace(/[^A-z0-9]/ig, '-') + '-cisession';
if($.cookie(cookieSessionName) !== null) {
    Session.set({ id: $.cookie(cookieSessionName) });
    Session.fetch({
        success: function()
        {
            $('.user-name').html('Hi, '+Session.get('first_name'));
            $('.logged-in').show();
            $('.logged-out').hide();
            property.collection.fetch();
            owners.collection.fetch();
        }
    });
} else {
    $('.logged-out').show();
    $('.logged-in').hide();
}

Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, root: '/' });
```

Comment: To people viewing this I am about to visit this again, hopefully have an answer.